# How do I save form data using react-router-dom?

Tags: react-router-dom

I have a route with a component that displays some form data. When I hit the submit button, I'll navigate to a different route that contains a receipt. If the user hits the back button, I want to remember what was entered in the form. How can I achieve this when using react-router-dom?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is some type of data/state management for your react application.

[Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) is a good example for this. Search up how mobx works and how you can use this together with react.

With Mobx, you can store the user's form inputs in some type of class that you can decorate with mobx (for example DataStore class), which you can then read on your other page when you navigate there with router.

Comment: Alternatively, just save the user's inputs in variables every time they type something by using an 'input' event on the form fields. When you navigate to the other page, read them from those variables again.